# Are there MapReduce implementations on GPUs (CUDA)?

Tags: cuda, mapreduce, gpu

So far, I'm aware of the [Mars](http://www.cse.ust.hk/gpuqp/Mars_tr.pdf), though what about alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present, the easiest interface is provided by [thrust::reduce](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide#Reductions).

As you noted, there is also [Mars](https://web.archive.org/web/20181027143828/http://gpgpu.org/tag/mapreduce).

Comment: What thrust::reduce does is not what I'd call map-reduce.  thrust::reduce is the reduce function found in many functional programming contexts that turns a sequence, a starting value, and a binary operation into a single value.  In Scala, it's called "foldLeft" or "foldRight" but in most functional programming languages it's called "reduce".  The reduce stage of a map-reduce algorithm performs some operation on a set of values associated with a key, but this operation is not necessary binary and doesn't necessarily turn the sequence into a single value.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I have implemented [cumar](https://github.com/fengwang/cumar).

As I was using Mac OS X and 'nvcc' compiler was not happy with Apple's 'clang', I designed this library pure C++ ( and a flavor of lambda ).

A typical map operation looks like this:

```
//A = B + C, all of length 'n'
cumar::map()("[](double a&, double b, double c){ a = b+c; }" )(A, A+n, B, C);
```

For reduce operation, it looks like this:

```
// x = min(A), A of size 'n'
cumar::reduce()( "[](double a, double b){ return a < b ? a : b; }" )(A, A+n);
```